# Windows Phone 8.1: Open an Existing SQLite3 database

Tags: windows-phone-8, sqlite

I have an `SQLite3` database that contains multiple choice questions. I am able to very quickly and easily use this database in both my Android and iOS applications. However, I have come to write a Windows Phone 8.1 version of apps and I'm finding the process much more difficult.

I have added a couple of packages and references to my project. I have used `nuget` to add two packages, `sqlite-net` and `System.Data.SQLite`, and I have also added a reference to `SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1`.

I have dropped my database file into the project's Assets folder. It's called `questionsDb.db`. I have changed its build actions property to `content` and set the option to `always copy`.

I have written the following model class:

```
using SQLite;

namespace MyApp
{
class Question
{


    [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
    public int _id { get; set; }

    [Indexed]
    public string question { get; set; }
    public string answer { get; set; }
    public string incorrect1 { get; set; }
    public string incorrect2 { get; set; }
    public string incorrect3 { get; set; }
    public int difficulty { get; set; }
}
}
```

I then have the following code which is intended to open the database and select the first question:

```
var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection( ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\questionsDb.db");
Question q = new Question();
q = db.Query<Question>("select * from questions where _id = 1")[0];
```

When I run this code SQLite does try to open a database, but I get an error message saying:

```
Additional information: Could not open database file: C:\Data\Users\DefApps\APPDATA\Local\Packages\3697fbe8-2d3f-455f-ad78-2bce9035bd82_gd9wj2p7c52jg\LocalState\questionsDb.db (CannotOpen)
```

I have tried numerous different file paths for the database, such as:

1. questionsDb.db
2. Assets\questionsDb.db
3. ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\Assets\questionsDb.db"

I am very new to Windows Phone so this may be a simple fix, but I'd be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Files which build action is set to Content are copied to the app's folder. So you need to copy the database to the appdata folder.

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///questionsDb.db"));
// You can open the file now, using file.Path, but files in the app's folder are read-only
// so you better to copy it to the local storage
var copiedFile = await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
// Now you can open the database
var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(copiedFile.Path);
Question q = new Question();
q = db.Query<Question>("select * from questions where _id = 1")[0];
```